# Absolut minimum of code in 1 aspx file that wakes .NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

What would you write as an absolut minimum to write a aspx file? The purpose is to force the .net handler to run. Sometimes I want to make a short handwrited code to check the iis functionality. It's easy in older languages.

HTML
Hello World

ASP
`<% Response.Write("Hello World") %>`

ASP.NET
This works just fine but so clumsy - yes.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Hello World!");
    }
</script>
```

System.Environment.Version is nice, though, if also check the version. Is all this code really needed for asp.net? It isn't a code you just "hand print just for sake to check".

Comment: I do not see what you are trying to achieve. Save Your hello world html as .aspx and it will work fine

Comment: @Pleun: He wants to ensure .aspx files are being handled by the .net handler. He wants the absolute minimum for that.

Comment: @Pleun Question edited for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The absolute minimum is, or could be construed to be:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%
    Response.Write("test");
%>
```

Comment: No, the minimum is a blank file. But further to that; it's probably unneccessary to do the response.write if you just want to verify if asp.net is running. That it doesn't output the directive would be enough to confirm. But it's a technical complaint, really.

Comment: @Noon, I took the OPs question to imply minimum that *does something*, given that they say in the question "*I want to fastly manual handwrite a asp.net page to check the iis functionality*", i.e. is asp.net actually working/installed? Yes - just the `<%@` would do, but a blank page could be caused by something else. The `Response.Write` proves beyond any doubt that asp.net has executed the code.

Comment: @Rob as did I; hence the upvote. I was marking a snarky comment, at best, on the language in this post.

Comment: Well.. we have world-wide language coding standards. Though, we create comments and docs to make other understand ;). So <%@ is a key for wake the .NET handler? And then the output.. Pretty.

Comment: @Jonas, the fact that the file extension (`.aspx`) is mapped within IIS to the ASP.NET handler (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll` or `System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory` depending on which mode the app pool is running in), is what "wakes" the ASP.NET handler =)

Answer (score 0):

Rob, Could this be like below ?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Hello World!");
    }
```

As it is for ASP>net tag

Comment: you don't have to use event handlers within the asp.net page's framework to verify that asp.net is running

Answer (score 0):

if the purpose is to run .net handler, the minimum is **blank file with aspx extension**.
*Page Language="C#"* is not required, since C# is the default language.