# Allow HTTP Post to Network FO

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a customer that needs to receive XML files to a shared network folder via HTTPPOST.  I am a Network guy, so I have zero programming background.  Can someone share advice about how I would go about adding an asp.net application to IIS 8 that will allow customer to receive XML files without forms or other user interaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial way would be to drop a [minimal .ASPX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975561/absolut-minimum-of-code-in-1-aspx-file-that-wakes-net) that writes the request body to disk:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%
    foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss.xml");
        var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\UploadedFiles\", dateTime);
        file.SaveAs(filename);
    }
%>
```

But as a network guy you'll know this opens up your server to a whole lot of abuse, so make sure to secure it properly.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance on the subject, but would I create an asp.net web site, or an application that will run with an IIS website.  Not sure if I need to create a generic IIS site and have this code run as an app underneath it.

Comment: You can just save this as an .aspx file and drop it in an IIS Website (or subdirectory, or Application under a Website). Do note it's untested, but the general idea should work. IIS will compile the file on demand.

Comment: I saved the file and I receive the following error:

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Source Error:
Line 4:      foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)
Line 5:      {
Line 6:          var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss.xml");
Line 7:          var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\UploadedFiles\", dateTime);
Line 8:          file.SaveAs(filename);
 Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\post.aspx    Line: 6

Comment: That means the app pool is running .NET 2.0. Replace `var` with `string`, or change the app pool to run .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CodeCaster! Moved to .Net 4 and get 200OK on POST. Really appreciate the help.